# bitBucketのwebページにベーシック認証について

Tags: git, bitbucket

はじめまして！
gitクライアントのbitBucketを使用して静的なwebページを
`http://ユーザー名.bitbucket.org` で見せることは可能なのですが

その場合ルートに.htaccessを設置して下記のフルパスを設置してパスワードをかけます。

```
AuthUserFile フルパス/.htpasswd
```

ですがルートに.htpasswdを設置する場合.htpasswdフルパスは何になるのでしょうか。

大変お手数ではございますがご教示頂ければ幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 英語版での質問 http://stackoverflow.com/q/33114634/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic認証も Rewrite もそうですが、そもそも `.htaccess` に対応していません。過去に要望は出ていますが、却下されていました。

> Sorry, I'm just gonna say we're not doing this.
>   <sub>--- https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5325/control-access-to-bitbucket-pages-with より引用</sub>

参考までに、類似サービスである Github Pages でもやはりサポートされていないようです。

> For the security of our users, GitHub Pages does not support customer server configuration files such as `.htaccess` or `.conf`.
>   <sub>--- https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/ より引用</sub>

Comment: そうなのですね。

色々調べてみるとレンタルサーバーに自動でデプロイする方法が
あるのはそういった兼ね合いなのでしょうか。

[http://berry22.com/blog/bitbucket-sakura-auto-deploy/]

Comment: @project そのページに書かれている手順のうち、Bitbucket側の対応は「pushされたことを特定のURLに通知する」という機能ですが、これはアプリケーションの自動テストなどにも広く用いられる機能です。GithubやBitbucket はあくまでソースコードを共有するのがメインのサイトですから、ついでに（一般公開される）プロジェクトページもホスティングできるといいよね、程度のおまけ機能だと私は考えています。

Comment: htmlなどをレンタルサーバーのように使用できて尚且つバージョン管理できればなぁと考えておりました。上記の機能も含めて環境を整えれるようにがんばります。本当にありがとうございます。